# AMC $12$ question on probability

Tags: probability, permutations

Each face of a cube is painted either red or blue, each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. The color of each face is determined independently. What is the probability that the painted cube can be placed on a horizontal surface so that the four vertical faces are all the same color?

The probability of each instance is $(1/2)^6$. So for $4$ colors the same, there are $2$ scenarios and for $5$ colors the same, there is also $2$ scenarios, for $6$ colors the same it is $1$ scenario. My result is $\frac{5}{64}\cdot 2$ since red and blue can be the same color.
 Thus I get $5/32$.

Is my solution correct and why don't rotations add to the scenario. I don't grasp this fully quite yet.

Comment: Here is the official solution: http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2004_AMC_10B_Problems/Problem_23.

Is there something you don't understand there?

Comment: @IsaacBrowne why are the scenarios in which the the vertical faces do not have the same color counted in the desirable outcomes

Answer (score 1):

Note that the question asks for the probability that the cube *can* be placed. That means we don't start with 4 designated vertical faces; we have freedom to choose which faces to place vertical.

There are 3 scenarios in which four vertical faces are red and two blue: pick any pair of opposing faces of the cube to be blue, and the rest red. Then we can choose to place the cube blue-face-down, so the red faces come out vertical. There are 3 such pairs (since there are 6 faces).

There are 6 scenarios in which five faces are red and one blue: pick any particular face to be blue, then we can choose to place the cube blue-face-down (or blue-face-up), and the red faces come out vertical.

There is 1 scenario in which six faces are red. The red faces will come out vertical no matter how we place the cube.

So there should be a total of 10 scenarios in which we can place the cube with four vertical red faces. As you alluded to, the same argument goes through for blue faces, giving 20 scenarios in total. So the probability should be $\frac{20}{64}$

Comment: why are the scenarios in which the the vertical faces do not have the same color counted in the desirable outcomes

Comment: @jamarcus can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 The scenarios in which the vertical faces are not the same color are chosen why is this so and isnt the whole problem under the assumption that the cube is fixed

Comment: @jamarcustyrone Precisely which scenarios are being counted which you think should not be?

Comment: @jamarcustyrone What do you mean by "fixed"? My interpretation of the problem is that we can rotate the cube after we paint it and before we place it on the horizontal surface.

Comment: No! The cube is not fixed, we can rotate it to choose which four faces we want vertical.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 is that not overcounting i am a jr in hs preparing for amc 12 what do you reccomend to solidify my understanding of combinatics

Comment: @jamarcustyrone It's not overcounting because we are fixing the cube in place as we count it, but as we are considering the cases, we allow consideration of rotation.  If you are interested in problem solving, - Visit AOPS - Maybe read aops vol. 1&2 - use AOPS's Alcumus for practice - Definitely do more AMC problems - AOPS also has classes and books of different topics that may interest you. Unfortunately, since the AMC is in about a month and a half, you won't we able to do all of this, so pick your battles wisely.

Comment: @greenturtle3141  I still don't understand I will dedicate all my time to do amc

Comment: Is there a reason why the rotations are included in the . It is because it is a permutation right